# Paypal Button Incorrectly Formatted Item Amount

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, paypal

Cheers guys!
I am having issues with my paypal button in my ASP.NET C# project, whenever I click the "Add To Cart", paypal gives me the following error:

"*The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount.*"

My button looks like this:

```
 <form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="MyEmail@Email.com">
                <!-- Specify a PayPal Shopping Cart Add to Cart button. -->
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
                <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<%# Eval("ProductName") %>">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%# Eval("ProductPrice", "{0:0.00}") %>">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="DKK">
                <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif"
                    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
                <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
                </form>
```

In my SQL Database my "**ProductPrice**" is a **datatype: decimal(18, 0)**
I tried to change it to **datatype: money**, but without much success.

I would like to mention that I am NOT an experienced coder/programmer like you guys, and every reply I recieve will be MUCH appreciated from my side :)

Thank you!

Comment: Check the generated HTML. In browser in the page where this button is, view the html source code. See what is the value set for `amount`

Comment: Hey Erfan, the HTML generated for Amount is: <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="99,00">

Comment: Now you see the problem :) it should be **99.00** not **99,00**. PayPal will accept only dot(.) as decimal separator, not comma

Comment: Oh snap! That is a problem yes! But as I mentioned, I am not an experienced programmer so I'd like to know, how I change the it to a dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%# Eval("ProductPrice", "{0:0.00}").ToString().Replace(",", ".") %>">
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It works like a charm, your help is much appreciated Erfan, thank you!